# React-Native production app crashes all of sudden

Tags: android, react-native, crash

One of my customers is facing App crash issue suddenly. It was working well till yesterday. But when opened today it crashed as soon as splash screen loading is completed. It's happening in only one device(**Redmi Y2**). App was uninstalled and newly installed from **Playstore** but no use.

App is working well with in device **Honor 9N** and unable to debug the issue since i don't have **Redmi Y2** where App crash is happening.

**My Analysis as of now:**

I can confirm that `App` is crashed before executing the `Java Script` code. I checked this by running sample `apk` in his mobile(I mailed him test `apk` link). I could not check what's happening form native `Android` side since I am a `react-native` developer.

Is it possible to see crash logs by using [react-native-codepush](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push) [appcenter-analytics](https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter-sdk-react-native/blob/master/appcenter-analytics/README.md)?

OR

Is there any workaround to find the root cause of the `App` crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you could try to integrate [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsqensObA-AIV7QyLCh0sAwqbEAAYASAAEgIPX_D_BwE) into your app. It is free and will send you detailed information about any crashes and hang-ups in your app.

Comment: I have also same problem my app is related to shopping when I create release apk it successfully created but  whenever I try to run in my device it and it runs successfully but whenever my senior try to run this app in our device it's not open it's crash again and again so what I can do and where is my error??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get data from the AppCenter Analytics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/react-native

An idea to find the root cause -> If your customer can assist you and connect the device (with dev options enabled) to a PC with Android Studio installed you can see exactly what's crashing from the Logcat.